# Psshutdown Remote Computer With Computer Name Not working

Tags: networking, shutdown, computer-name

I have been trying to fix this issue for months and just can't seem figure it out. Both computers Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit. Trying to shut down a remote computer in my LAN home network. I'm using psshutdown which is part of the Microsoft PsTools.

psshutdown \\computer name -s -t 01 (does not work) and I get this error:

Couldn't access Computer name:
Access is denied.

If computer name is already performing a shutdown operation you must
abort it before issuing a different command.

When I use the following:
psshutdown \\computer ip address -s -t 01 (it works).

I would like to use the computer name, can anyone help? I have tried searching nothing works.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried shutdown using shutdown /s or r or h via CMD prompt or Powershell.  If it's your home network the reason why you have to use your IP address might because you don't have a Active Directory resource to manage the computer name.  Also you can try using Team Viewer, its a great and free RDP program.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I have tried PowerShell and I get the same message as I did with CMD prompt. I use TeamViewer and am aware of its capabilities. I would like to use the psshutdown in my batch file. Never had to do anything with Active Directory for this to work in the past.